# Highcharts: Make the Axis continue to current datetime

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I am making a chart that shows the rate and it is a step chart using the datetime axis which is perfect for what i need to do. There are only data points for when the rate is changed. I can not find a way to make the axis continue to a specific datetime. Example might be current time! The second this is that i want the line to continue to the end as well. To do this is would seem i would need to artificially enter a data point to solve both issues.

So a practical example might be that you start the system and the rate gets set to 10 and you look at this chart an hour later you would see a point from start time to the current time.

http://jsfiddle.net/nexeh/hfeoryks/1/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x',
                spacingRight: 20,
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Rate'
            },
             xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Time'
                },
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    format: 'rate'
                }
            },

             plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    step: 'left'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Time/Date',
                data: [[1456187667884,10],[1456187670916,10],[1456187671364,10],[1456187671562,10],[1456188795998,15],[1456188824877,0],[1456189436947,15],[1456189479375,25],[1456189597814,15],[1456189606222,0],[1456189626203,15],[1456191553211,0],[1456191604041,15],[1456191684985,22],[1456191911371,15],[1456191911922,0],[1456192571955,15],[1456192775431,19],[1456193247974,15],[1456193248525,0],[1456193273059,15],[1456198143933,0]]
            }]
        });
```

});

Comment: You can add another point in the array, which will duplicate the last value, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hfeoryks/3/

Comment: @PawełFus Thank you. I wanted to check there wasn't a option i was missing for this use case. I know that you are very knowledgeable in this area because you have answered other questions i have had in the past. Given our history i am willing to accept this as an answer if you'd like to submit it. Thank you for taking the time again to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution will be to duplicate the last point with a given timestamp (e.g. current time). For example: http://jsfiddle.net/hfeoryks/3

Snippet:

```
var endTime = 1456198143933 + 3600 * 1000,
    data = [
      [1456187667884, 10],
      [1456187670916, 10],
      ...
      [1456193273059, 15],
      [1456198143933, 0]
    ];

data.push([endTime, data[data.length - 1][1]]);
```

And now apply updated data:

```
series: [{
  data: data
}]
```

======================

There is another solution, to write simple plugin for Highcharts, which will do exactly the same (adding extra point at the end of array):

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'init', function (p) {
    var options = arguments[2],
        UNDEFINED;
    if (options.data && options.endTime !== UNDEFINED) {
      options.data.push([options.endTime, options.data[options.data.length - 1][1]]);
    }
    p.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
  });
})(Highcharts)
```

Now just set new option `series.endTime` (or whatever you like to call it):

```
series: [{
  endTime: +new Date(),
  name: 'Time/Date',
  data: [
    [1456187667884, 10],
    [1456187670916, 10],
    ...
    [1456193273059, 15],
    [1456198143933, 0]
  ]
}]
```

});

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hfeoryks/6/

Comment: As always, a complete answer that goes above and beyond. Thank you Pawel.